# Chart JS Replace All Dataset Data

Tags: chart.js, chartjs-2.6.0

I want to replace my chart data entirely with a new array of objects. The chart data was replaced by new data but the chart is not updating after I called mychart.update(). Is there any way to replace the entire data without destroying the chart?

Here's my code:

```
  Livewire.on('changeData', () => {
    myChart.data.datasets.data = @this.data;
    myChart.update();

    console.log(myChart.data.datasets.data);
  })
```

Old Data

[image: Old Data]

New Data

[image: New Data]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are doing it wrong, the `datasets` field is an array containing all datasets so it doesn't contain a `data` field. You need to target the specific dataset from which you want to replace the data like so:

```js
myChart.data.datasets[datasetIndex].data = @this.data; // in case you only have 1 dataset you can just hardcode a 0
myChart.update();
```

Comment: I just realized the dataset is an array. Thank you for the solution, will accept this solution in 10 minutes.